# Returning a list of objects

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am writing a function that will return a list (or a vector- not sure about that yet) of objects, and I am wondering how to implement it.

At first I thought something along like:

```
int getVector(ObjectVectorType MyVector, some other arguments here);
```

Then I thought,. ummm maybe

```
ObjectVectorType getVector(int *nElementsOfVector, some other arguments here);
```

But then I remember, that a vector type has `size()` so maybe it is not even necessary to get the number of elements the first time... maybe size does not take much time...

Any advice on this , before i start coding?

Thanks

Comment: `ObjectVectorType getVector(some other arguments here)`.

Comment: You want the function to *take* a vector and *return* a vector, is that right?

Comment: Not really. Right now, the function will get an image (unrelated) and return a vector that didn't exist previously. However, if you have any advice or insight related to functions that take and return a vector, I am all ears to hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectVectorType getVector(some other arguments here);
```

Use return values to return values from functions.

Vectors are contiguous collections of elements, and are cheap to return thanks to elision and move semantics.